# Зачем при оптимизации копировать, инкрементировать, и копировать обратно?

Tags: ассемблер

Код ассемблера ниже, если включена оптимизация Maximize Speed:

```
; 30   :                i = i + 1;

mov eax, DWORD PTR tv329[ebp]
mov ecx, DWORD PTR tv328[ebp]
inc ebx
inc eax
add ecx, 4
mov DWORD PTR tv329[ebp], eax
mov DWORD PTR tv328[ebp], ecx
```

А этот код с оптимизацией Minimize Size

```
; 30   :                i = i + 1;

inc edx
inc esi
add edi, 4
```

Операция в программе i = i + 1

Вопрос, зачем при оптимизации по скорости нужно копировать из DWORD PTR tv329[ebp] в eax, инкрементировать, а копировать обратно? Это помогает в скорости? Но как.

Обновление:

Maximize Speed: https://ideone.com/8JKULj
Minimize Size: https://ideone.com/zbnv8n

Обновление 2:
Оптимизация по скорости:

```
; 14   :      do {
; 15   :         i = g;

mov ebx, ecx
xor eax, eax
lea ecx, DWORD PTR _arr$[ebp+ecx*4]
mov DWORD PTR tv329[ebp], eax
mov DWORD PTR tv328[ebp], ecx
npad    1
```

Оптимизация по размеру:

```
; 14   :      do {
; 15   :         i = g;

lea edi, DWORD PTR _arr$[ebp]
mov edx, eax
xor esi, esi
lea edi, DWORD PTR [edi+eax*4]
```

Зачем в оптимизации по размеру в lea заносить один адрес, потом выполнять действия, не связанные с lea и с _arr$, а затем опять заносить в lea уже другой адрес?

Comment: Нужно рассматривать код большего размера. Желательно целой функции. Второй образец увеличивает содержимое двух регистров на 1, и зачем то edi на 4 - что никак к i=i+1 не относится. В первом случае похоже что i и еще что то загружается из памяти потом к ним прибавляют 1 и 4 и опять кладут в память. Возможно оптимизатор решил не класть эти переменные в регистры на постоянно потому что регистры используются под другие более важные переменные. А может просто крышу ему снесло.

Comment: Выбранные оптимизации влияют на то, какие переменные будут располагаться в регистрах, а какие — в памяти. Вы должны смотреть на целую картину: наверняка вытеснение какого-нибудь регистра в память освобождает этот регистр для других переменных, и _в целом_ ускоряет программу.

Comment: Обновил, добавил полностью

Answer (score 7, accepted):

На вопрос в заглавии ответ - инкрементировать непосредственно в памяти процессор не умеет, поэтому надо вытащить значение в регистр, увеличить и положить в память обратно.

Конкретно приведенный в тексте вопроса кусок разумеется работает дольше, чем если бы `i` была просто в регистре. Но если рассмотреть весь код целиком, то выясняется, что переменная `i` по факту в цикле практически не используется и что самое важное - она не используется для обращения к массивам по индексу.

Зато в полном оптимизированном по скорости коде видно, что основные переменные по которым идут обращения к массиву - постоянно в регистрах, флажок `bool c` даже в регистре `dl`. В *целом* количество обращений к памяти в самой середине циклов (которые выполняются больше всего раз) меньше. Обращения к памяти для работы с флагом `c` так же отсутствуют.

Сравните например `if` в 20 строке и `c=false`в 21:

```
mov edi, DWORD PTR _arr$[ebp+eax*4]           mov   eax, DWORD PTR _arr$[ebp+ecx*4]
mov esi, DWORD PTR [ecx]                      mov   DWORD PTR _tmp$1$[ebp], eax
                                              mov   eax, DWORD PTR [ebx]
cmp edi, esi                                  cmp   DWORD PTR _tmp$1$[ebp], eax
jg  SHORT $LN3@main                           jg    SHORT $LN3@main

                           ; 21: c=false
xor dl, dl                                    mov   BYTE PTR _c$1$[ebp], 0
```

При оптимизации по скорости загружаем данные из 2х ячеек памяти, сравниваем и переходим. При оптимизации по размеру два "лишних" обращения к памяти. Причем часть из них самого if не касается, это похоже нужно позже, просто оптимизатор решил нарисовать их здесь. И в отличии от куска кода который не понравился вам, данная строка находится в 3 по вложенности цикле и выполняется явно гораздо больше раз, чем пресловутое i++;  А флажок `c` в первом случае вообще мгновенный, во втором это загрузка константы по адресу в памяти, один из самых медленных вариантов `mov`, а ведь его потом еще проверяют так же доставая из памяти ...

Итого - при оптимизации по скорости самые важные переменные постоянно в регистрах, а под менее важную переменную `i` уже не хватило регистров, поэтому ее оставили в памяти и обращаются по мере необходимости.

P.S. А вообще оптимизатор жутко умный. я даже немного не ожидал от него такого (выдержки из вашего кода):

```
int n=10;
...
n = n - 1;                   mov    DWORD PTR _arr$[ebp+4], 9
" Он понял, что в память надо сразу занести 9, а не пытаться грузить 10 и вычитать"
while (i <= n)               cmp    ebx, 9
" Он видит что n нигде не меняется и использует его как константу"

g = (n + 1) / 2;             mov   ecx, 5
" Он знает что n константа (9), значит g=5, вычислять опять не надо"

 do {
     i = g;                  xor    eax, eax
     do {                    ; В eax он будет далее в цикле вести j
         j = i - g;            и поэтому перед циклом он просто делает ее 0
" Он понял, что на первой итерации i=g и не пытался вычислять j через i и g"

         if(arr[j+g]...      mov    esi, DWORD PTR [ecx]
" Вот это вообще гениально: он помнит, что в начале j=0
  а в ecx он заранее загрузил адрес массива + g*4 (4 это размер элемента массива int)
  И когда вы пишите arr[j+g] он просто лезет в память по регистру ecx"

j = j - 1;                  dec eax    ; В eax j - тут все ясно, вычли 1
                            sub ecx, 4 ; А это зачем ???
"Я все никак не мог понять, почему при вычитании 1 из j еще 4 вычитается из ecx
Но ларчик просто открывался, в ecx у нас, как мы помним, адрес элемента массива arr
с индексом [j+g], а т.к. j уменьшается, а g в обозримом будущем меняться не собирается,
то мы просто вычитаем из адреса 4, т.е. размер одного элемента массива
и таким образом нам в цикле вычислять arr+i+g вообще не надо, мы его всегда знаем"

"В приведенном коде сравнения 2х оптимизаторов был if(arr[j]<=arr[j+g]) который в конечном
 счете был cmp esi,edi; Так вот, значения элементов массива в регистрах далее по тексту
 не пропадает:"
tmp = arr[j];
arr[j] = arr[j+g];          mov DWORD PTR _arr$[ebp+eax*4], esi
arr[j+g] = tmp;             mov DWORD PTR [ecx], edi
"Нашей переменной tmp вообще нет, оптимизатор посчитал, что она не нужна и просто
 занес уже имеющиеся в регистрах значения arr[j] и arr[j+g] в массив, а в варианте 
 с оптимизацией по объему tmp была ... "
```

Дополнение на основе дополнения в вопросе :)

```
lea edi, DWORD PTR _arr$[ebp]
mov edx, eax
xor esi, esi
lea edi, DWORD PTR [edi+eax*4]
```

Почему он выбирает именно такой порядок инструкций сказать сложно, на размер это ни как не влияет, может влиять например на кеш данных у процессора, или на параллельность выполнения команд. И lea не в себя грузит адрес, а грузит его в указанный регистр, в данном случае edi. Первый lea грузит в edi адрес массива arr, а второй lea грузит адрес уже с использованием того edi, который подготовил первый lea. А конкретно он выполняет `edi=edi+eax*4`, ну т.е. второй lea эквивалентен четырем подряд `add edi,eax`, но разумеется быстрее и меньше в размере

Comment: Спасибо за анализ. Я обновил вопрос, добавил кое-что

Comment: @thejadefalcon  Добавил кое-что в ответ :)

Comment: Спасибо, не заметил что второй lea использует edi